# Design-time view attributes as images issue

Tags: android, sample-data

I am facing an issue with sample data *.png. I have created sample data directory. Then I went a ahead & created json file for mapping data to recycler view items. The layout item file text views property tools:text set to this json property and layout designer shows the items populated with text. Now I wanted to put images to there placeholders so I have created a directory. In this case the list was category, so I had created a folder named categories and put the *.pngs there. After which I have used set sample data option to that image view. But the problem is they are not appearing in layout designer, but I can set the sample data to default provided options by android studio.

How can I make my own resources get to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works only on Android Studio 3.5 Beta 1 only, I guess.